# Biztalk 2013 - Promoted schema property is getting dropped?

Tags: c#, biztalk

I have configured a WCF-WebHttp BizTalk Request/Response Static pipeline adaptor with the following URL mapping

```
<BtsHttpUrlMapping>
<Operation Name="Query_ADM" Method="GET" Url="{MYVARIABLE}" />
</BtsHttpUrlMapping>
```

In the Variable Mapping I have set the variable name MYVARIABLE to a property called id in the defining schema of the message. I have set the property namespace of the defining schema - in the variable mapping - which is also published to the same application.

The id has been promoted in the schema and I can see this promotion if I trace this through the tracked message events.

However at the point there the logical send/receive port sends the message through the physical port - it appears the promotion of the id field is dropped.

There is a transmission failure message with

> The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "MY_PORT"
>   with URL
>   "http://myurl.dev.application.com/api/v2/crm/accounts/". It
>   will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send
>   Port. Details:"System.ArgumentException: The path variable
>   'MYVARIABLE' in the UriTemplate must be bound to a non-empty string
>   value.

Everything looks setup okay? Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks.

Here's the schema with promoted (and distinguished) id property field.

[image: Schema]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - so when setting the variable mapping it seems I was using the wrong property namespace. I was using the namespace of the XSD that contained the property when I should have been explicitly using the namespace of the property promotion schema itself. That appears to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you seem to be using a Distinguished Field, instead of a Property Field. Distinguished fields are only accessible within orchestrations. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561059.aspx) for an explanation.

You need to create a property schema in order to promote your property to a Property Field.

(Make sure you're using an XMLTransmit pipeline on the send part of the WCF-WebHttp port (or any pipeline with an XML assembler component). Otherwise the adapter won't recognise promoted properties in the message.)

Comment: thanks James - I'm using an XML Transmit pipeline in the send part of the port. I'm beginning to think it might be something to do with the way the id field is defined in the schema - affecting the way the promotion is bound to the URL variable - it is xs:string

Comment: hi James - have added the schema. the promoted property is in there. I wonder if it is anything to do with the ns0: prefixes messing the binding up?

Comment: The error message is "The path variable 'MYVARIABLE' in the UriTemplate must be bound to a non-empty string value" - the promoted property is just not getting through. If I hardcode the URL /accounts/15 it works okay. Tracing the message from the input XML file through - I can see it is promoted for a few message jumps within the orchestration - but gets dropped somewhere in the outbound port - even though it iis using an XML Pipeline.

Comment: See my edited answer. You need to use a Property field instead of a distinguished field

Comment: Yep, I do understand that. I initially promoted the field - which created a property schema. I could see the promoted field in the message tracking - but it got dropped in the send port somehow. I agree that using a non XML pipeline would cause this behaviour - but the port is using XML transmit. In a desperate attempt to get it working I additionally distinguished the field to no avail. I've gone back to basics and done the most simple project - have same issue - must be doing something wrong somewhere. I'll keep trying, thank you for your advise though.